# Public, trusted certificate for an invalid domain that can be used for testing

Tags: security, ssl, testing

For a lot of development environments testing with a self-signed certificate or custom CA is impossible or tedious (e.g. Node.js currently does not allow its certificate store to be changed). Has any generally trusted CA published a certificate and its private key for an invalid domain (e.g. with CN:*.testing) that could be used for software testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know. That would be risky, as you would have also to publish the private key. AFAIK there is also a policy that requires CA to revoke a certificate if there is an evidence that the private key was compromised or published.

My best suggestion is to purchase a test domain and use it. There are several new gTLDs that are reasonably cheap and you can get a decent name at a very low cost (eg. the `.codes` or `.build` may fit your needs).

Then you'll be able to get a certificate for it and use something like Let's Encrypt to issue the certificate for free (so that you will only pay the cost of the domain). Finally, simply adopt that domain locally for development (e.g. setting the `whatever.build` to point to `127.0.0.1`.